# Java LocalDate is not working within Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working in a Spring Batch project. I have bean that reads data from SQL Server DB. With in the read query, I am setting date to extract information from table. The problem is I am using `String.format()` method to set query date parameters using `LocalDate`. I have to add one day with current date. The bean is being initialized without any issues and on first run the query is run as per requirement but during consecutive run the `LocalDate` is generating only current date without adding 1 day.

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<SchoolOrders> getOrdersInAdvance(){
JdbcCursorItemReader<SchoolOrders> jdbcCursorReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
String query = String.format("SELECT ORDER_NUMBER,STORE_NUMBER,PAYMENTINFO FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_DATE=%1$s",new Object[]{LocalDate.now(ZoneID.of("Asia/Kolkata")).plusDays(1)});
jdbcCursorReader .setDataSource(dataSource);
jdbcCursorReader .setSql(query);
jdbcCursorReader .setVerifyCurosrPosition(true);
jdbcCursorReader .setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyMapper<SchoolOrders>(SchoolOrders.class));
returns jdbcCursorReader;
}
```

I know `LocalDate` is immutable but the date is not persisted within object level and generated instantly.

Can someone please help me in resolving this issue! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean by consecutive run?

Comment: Use Dateformatter to format LocalDate into String

Comment: @DeepakKumar The job is running once in a day, during very first run (after server starts up) its working as expected. But next day its running with particular day's date not plus 1 days as defined.

Comment: @Rono yeah i tried that as well, its not working as expected.

Comment: @JayendranGurumoorthy Did you check for the 3rd day ? Seems like timezone issue, maybe database and system are not sync with same time zone. And LocalDate don't store timezone info.

Comment: @Rono Database is running on UTC timezone, I've tried with Azure SQL Servers GETDATE() functionality but its picking up UTC time(compute) and that is not relevant to application requirement. Its totally weird I have done similar implementation in a REST call but batch is simply working little weird.

Comment: @JayendranGurumoorthy the issue seems of the scope of the bean. By default the scope of bean in spring is as singleton, That's why the object will be created and kept, and on each request the same object will be returned. Try with prototype scope, it should work.

Comment: Specify timezone in datasource url and remember to make false legacy timezone false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@Bean` to specify the `JdbcCursorItemReader<SchoolOrders>` results in a [singleton-scoped bean (default)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes).  The method `getOrdersInAdvance()` is therefore only run in its entirety once in order to configure the Spring Bean, and all subsequent calls will simply return the cached bean unless - as you have observed - the application is restarted.

If you have a date/time sensitive item within the Spring Bean that needs to be refreshed each time the `Job` or `Step` is executed, you can annotate that bean method with [`@JobScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/JobScope.html) or [`@StepScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/StepScope.html), respectively.

From what I can understand in your case, I would suggest you first try to configure your `JdbcCursorItemReader` as job-scoped.

```java
@Bean
@JobScope
public JdbcCursorItemReader<SchoolOrders> getOrdersInAdvance(){
  JdbcCursorItemReader<SchoolOrders> jdbcCursorReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
  String query = String.format("SELECT ORDER_NUMBER,STORE_NUMBER,PAYMENTINFO FROM ORDERS WHERE ORDER_DATE=%1$s",new Object[]{LocalDate.now(ZoneID.of("Asia/Kolkata")).plusDays(1)});
  jdbcCursorReader .setDataSource(dataSource);
  jdbcCursorReader .setSql(query);
  jdbcCursorReader .setVerifyCurosrPosition(true);
  jdbcCursorReader .setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyMapper<SchoolOrders>(SchoolOrders.class));
  return jdbcCursorReader;
}
```

I would also suggest you read the Spring Batch documentation for [late binding of job and step attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#late-binding).